# Naming convention for getting the primitive backing a type?

Tags: java, naming, coding-standards

I have a class that is backed by a `double` value, and I am wondering about accessor method names that preserve abstraction. Based on my experience in Java, there seems to be at least two precedents:

- `toDouble()`, which mirrors `toString()`
- `doubleValue()`, similar to `Double.doubleValue()` and `BigInteger.doubleValue()`

I need access to this value to perform some computations. Would it be most appropriate to return a double value as I've mentioned, or provide public `multiply()`, `add()`, etc. methods?

Is there any common practice or precedent for a class used in this way?

Comment: What language? In C or C# or C++, all of them would be horrible...

Comment: The examples I am working from are Java.

Comment: The `toType()` names make me think of *conversion*, rather than simple retrieval. I don't know of a widespread convention for naming retrieval functions, but there is one part of the C++ internal corporate libraries I interface with that uses `theType()` for them, which seems as good a choice as any.

Comment: Would it make things difficult to understand if `toType()` implied a conversion? If we're trying to maintain an abstraction, a method that returns any other representation, string, double, or anything else, could be considered a conversion.

Comment: We may have different use cases in mind. I assumed that "backed by a double" is public knowledge about your class, so that it would only make sense to have a `theDouble()` method.

Comment: I understand, and I definitely agree if that was the case. This method was originally called getValue but I wanted something more abstract, and I noticed Java had a few different ways of doing this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any documented preference, in Java, for either of these conventions?

The preference is that the end user has *no idea* what the backing primitive is for your type. This is encapsulation at its essence.

Now, if your object exposes an interface to get a `double` (regardless of what the backing datatype is), either because you're serializing your object, or because it makes sense to provide that interface, then do so. But the naming convention needs to specifically focus on what the data *is* (be a serialized form, seconds since unix epoch, etc.) not what it *does* (serve as the implementation details of your object).

Comment: My difficulty is that my class already represents what the data is. I've wrapped a primitive in order to include some validation and type safety. Now I need to get the primitive out in order to use it in some computation.

Comment: @cantido - then simply `Value` should suffice.

Comment: Would that give away too much implementation detail? If I change the backing primitive to something else, Value wouldn't be entirely correct.

Comment: @cantido - you can't have it both ways. Either you hide the implementation detail, or you use the value in some computation. I don't know what you're doing, so I can't say what is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's tackle this:

> Would it be most appropriate to return a double value as I've mentioned, or provide public `multiply()`, `add()`, etc. methods?

Should said class *know* how to multiply and add? Sounds like you are building a calculator implementation... I would say it really depends on which part of the calculator you are building this for. If this is the 'engine', then giving the class `multiply()` and `add()` methods may be feasible. If this is only representing part of the user input (e.g. a `Value` instance that wraps the `String` keyboard input of `"2"`, only to return `2` as a number for calculation later), then maybe you want to defer such operations to the 'engine'.